# .retryWhen, when successful then do x

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am implementing a websocket layer in my Angular project with auto-reconnect. I have the following code to perform the auto-reconnect, and it is working as expected.

I now need to execute a method/block of code when the re-subscription is successful. I have played around with do, catch etc but can not seem to wrap my brain around a solution.

if I understand the retryWhen operator it acts on the error state and basically passes a complete. I can see this because the original websocket is closed and a new one is open.

```
.messages
            .map(res => { return JSON.parse(res)})
            .retryWhen(
            attempts => {
              console.log(attempts)
              return attempts
                .do((error) => { return 1 })
                .mergeMap(
                (error, count) => {
                  console.log(`Wait ${count} seconds, then retry API!`);
                  return Observable.timer(count * 1000);
                })
            })
            .share()
```

- Is there a way/operator that will execute a method/block of code once
  the error is cleared and the child subscription re-subscribes
  successfully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ultimately had to solve this issue outside of the retryWhen operator chain. in the .do(error) operator inside the retryWhen operator I set a local Boolean value to true.

Then in my subscription to my websocket connectionStatus if connectionStatus == 1 to indicate the websocket has connected, and local variable == true then execute my block of code.

Seems I was over complicating things by trying to solve this problem purely in the retryWhen operator chain, I failed to realize I had other tools at my disposal to solve the problem.